# Why is PID 0xFEFF (65279) so common in SMB traffic?

Tags: wireshark, packet-capture, smb

I'm analyzing some SMB traffic between a test client running on Windows Server 2003 R2, opening, locking,and reading bits of a shared file on a Windows Server 2008 R2.  While much of the SMB traffic has the proper PID contained in it, some things always seem to have a PID of 0xFEFF.  For example, all my Locking, Trans2, and Close AndX Requests and Responses have 0xFEFF instead of the actual PID, whereas the Opens have the right PID.  Reads and Writes seem to have 0xFEFF also, though I think I've seen some with the right PID (but am not 100% sure at the moment).

My little test program is Python calling Win32 Create, ReadFile, LockFile, UnlockFile, and Close functions.  I'm really trying to track down some problems with Visual Foxpro experiencing odd errors, though.

Comment: I'd recommend installing the Microsoft Enterprise Hotfix Rollup on the server plus any Windows 7 clients that connect to it. Service-pack them up first. That rollup has many SMB-related fixes.

Comment: I'm pretty sure both servers are up-to-date as far as updates, but I'll look into that, thanks.

Comment: That rollup doesn't get delivered via Windows Update.